# PyQt: How to run GUI on Raspberry Pi desktop startup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am struggling with **running** a python script that executes **a PyQt5 GUI on desktop startup** of Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian Jessie.

**What do I have so far?**

- Python script with shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in first line (`python3 --version` is 3.4.2) running the GUI without any problems
- Shell script (.sh) that is able to execute the GUI with the following lines:

  `#!/bin/bash
  python3 GUI.py`

**Information that may help:**

- If I place both files in the same directory somewhere, the Shell script starts the GUI, but if they are on the desktop, it doesn't.
- Automatic login to desktop is enabled.

Thank you in advance for any help.

RaspiManu

**UPDATE:**

I solved my Problem with a lot of testing and posted an answer for other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I figured it out myself. Here's how it worked for me...

**Create autorun-file:**

2.1 LXTerminal: `cd /home/pi/.config/autostart`

2.2 LXTerminal: `sudo nano pythonscript.desktop`

2.3 pythonscript.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=YourName
Comment=Your comment
Exec=/home/pi/pythonscript.py -nograb #-nograb for comboBox on touch Screen
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/python.xpm
Path=/home/pi/
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

2.4 Ctrl+O, Ctrl+X, `sudo reboot`

**Good to know:**

It is important, that you can't use just any path to your script. The script has to be directly in the `/home/pi/` directory, so you would use `Exec=/home/pi/pythonscript.py` in the autorun-file (.desktop). I also learned, that if your script loads for example an image with PIL, this image has to be somewhere else, maybe on your desktop, because it can't be opened out of the `/home/pi/` directory.

If your GUI has a comboBox and you are using a touch screen, the comboBox might make your whole GUI unuseable after you touched it. Using `Exec=/home/pi/pythonscript.py -nograb` solves this problem.

`StartupNotify=true` is important for starting GUI scripts.

Hope this helps,

RaspiManu

Comment: I am following your answer and able to run pyqt5 application on startup. But its not loading the images. My project directory is inside `/home/pi/Documents/Project` which contains all the images. Do I need to move my project to /hom/pi/ as per your suggestion

Comment: Dear @SAndrew, this is a long time ago and I'm not completely sure. It's nice that your script runs on startup. When I did my GUI project, my script was located in `/home/pi/` directory. The python code of this script opened pictures out of a folder on my desktop (Raspbian Stretch). Maybe you could try loading pictures from a desktop folder, too. If this works, you have a reference and you can experiment with other location options that might work. I really hope, this helps you out. Good luck :)

Comment: What am I doing wrong? cd /home/pi/.config/autostart 
gave me this error:
 -bash: cd: /home/pi/.config/autostart: No such file or directory

Comment: Dear @Phönix64, this error means, that your system does not have that folder. The path to the autostart folder might have changed since 2018. As you can see in my original post, I worked with Raspbian Jessie which is outdated now. The system even had a whole name change from Raspbian to Raspberry Pi OS. I recommend you to do some research on the new location of the folder and try it again. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Jup thank you though that it was some kind of configuration step I missed but turns out that they completely changed the service structure. Now It works

Answer (score 0):

You can make a background service that runs on startup, by following this link
[Service method](https://serverfault.com/questions/135859/is-there-a-standard-way-to-make-daemon-in-debian?)

and By appending this line

```
service yourdaemon start
```

in /etc/rc.local

assuming your service name is 'yourdaemon'

Caution: Use the root previleges

Example service file

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          yourdaemon
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Your Daemon
# Description:       Your Daemon
### END INIT INFO

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Your Daemon"
NAME=yourdaemon
DAEMON=/hannext/yourdaemon.py  # Path to your python file
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
LOGFILE=/var/log/snc/$NAME.log


. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start()
{
        echo "$(date +%F) $(date +%T) DAEMON   : Starting $DESC service" >> $LOGFILE
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE --startas $DAEMON --make-pidfile --background
}

do_stop()
{
        echo "$(date +%F) $(date +%T) DAEMON   : Stopping $DESC service" >> $LOGFILE
        start-stop-daemon --stop $DAEMON --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE
        rm -f $PIDFILE
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
        #
        # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
        # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
        # then implement that here.
        #
        start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
        return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_start
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  stop)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  #reload|force-reload)
        #
        # If do_reload() is not implemented then leave this commented out
        # and leave 'force-reload' as an alias for 'restart'.
        #
        #log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
        #do_reload
        #log_end_msg $?
        #;;
  restart|force-reload)
        #
        # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
        # 'force-reload' alias
        #
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
          0|1)
                do_start
                case "$?" in
                        0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                        1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
                        *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
                esac
                ;;
          *)
                # Failed to stop
                log_end_msg 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
  *)
        #echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac

:
```

save it by the name of 'yourdaemon' in /etc/init.d/ and make it executable using

```
chmod +x yourdaemon
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and please excuse my question... I am very new to this and have never worked with daemons. I understand, that you can use the skeleton file in `/etc/init.d` for building one, but I looked into some other daemons like sudo or reboot and they seem to be written in C++ or C# which I am not able to use. Could you please explain the step of creating the daemon a bit more? And how do I use the root previleges?

Comment: I have edited my answer and included a sample script to make a service

Comment: You absolutely made my day for helping me this much. Thank you! I am not at work anymore, but I will definitely try it tomorrow and tell you about it.

Comment: Should `$NAME` stay as it is and use `NAME=yourdemon`, if this works like this, or do I have to change something more than `yourdemon` and the path to my .py file?

Comment: it is the name of the service so you should name it accordingly. Please mark it as correct if you find it helpful , after your testing.

Comment: I updated my question with the actual status. Hope it's ok that i used the original german paths and names.

Comment: DESC="Your Daemon"
NAME=yourdaemon
DAEMON=/yourfile/yourdaemon.py  # Path to your python file

if only these variables are changed in my script then I reckon it would work just fine. You don't have to change anything else

Comment: Thanks again for you answer. I changed the script like you said and updated my question with it and questions for the next steps, because sadly it still won't run.

Answer (score 0):

After doing this:
Create autorun-file:

**2.1 LXTerminal:** `cd /home/pi/.config/autostart`

**2.2 LXTerminal:** `sudo nano pythonscript.desktop`

**2.3** **pythonscript.desktop:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=YourName
Comment=Your comment
Exec=/home/pi/pythonscript.py -nograb #-nograb for comboBox on touch Screen
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/python.xpm
Path=/home/pi/
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;`
```

---

I discovered that just this line was missing: `chmod +x /home/pi/.config/autostart/pythonscript.desktop`