# How to run PyQt app on Raspberry pi startup?

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, touchscreen

I want to run a python file containing GUI made on PyQt5 when the raspberry pi starts. I can run the file from terminal without any problems but it is a manual procedure.
I tried following this post: [PyQt: How to run GUI on Raspberry Pi desktop startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367837/pyqt-how-to-run-gui-on-raspberry-pi-desktop-startup) but had no progress. My app won't start on raspberry pi startup.

Please note:

- I have enabled auto login to Desktop.
- PyQt5 is installed correctly.
- I am able to run python script with terminal and the app opens fine.

Thanks,

Gurpreet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making a new python file.
I ran this line:`os.getcwd()` which showed me the current directory in which program was running.

I found out that even thought my python file was placed in the `/home/pi/Desktop` directory, the program executed in the `/home/pi` directory and hence was searching for other files in the same directory.

So I moved all the program related files to the `/home/pi` directory and it started working as expected.