# Tkinter GUI does not run properly after auto boot

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I tried the solution provided in [Tkinter GUI does not run properly when auto boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395284/tkinter-gui-does-not-run-properly-when-auto-boot?answertab=active#tab-top) Tkinter, however GUI does not run properly when auto boot and got my python script with tkinter to run correctly and automatically after reboot.

The GUI interface kind of disappear. I get a black background, shows "Open Box" application when I tried to close, instead of the normal menu and wall paper. I can still right click and open web browser and a terminal. I tried running "startx" from terminal after some googling but received an error message.

How do I get the raspbian GUI interface working with the solution provided in link above? Any help is very much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
chmod +x /home/pi/Desktop/test.py
nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
@/home/pi/Desktop/test.py
```

Comment: Your question is better suited at [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @stovfl noted with thanks!